# Select revision (release) in Support Library reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

Is there a way to view the reference of a certain Android Support Library revision (like the API level selector at the Android Platform section)?

I'm following a tutorial that uses methods of revision 26 that I have not found at revision 27, for example: RecyclerView -> public T onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType).

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: "methods of revision 26 that I have not found at revision 27, for example: RecyclerView -> public T onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)." -- that method is on `RecyclerView.Adapter`, not `RecyclerView`, in both v26 and v27 of the support libraries.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. My confusion was due two things, first I was looking at the wrong place, and, mainly, in that method the tutorial called a ViewHolder constructor that used the same signature, but I didn't see that it wasn't overwriting it, so I was looking for that constructor at ViewHolder reference with no luck... Thanks.